# How to extract specific substrings and separate text from numbers in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have some data in a dataframe in the below format. Please see image link below

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXiWn.png)

The problem I'm trying to solve is two-fold

1. For the salary column and I want to separate the text and numbers and extract the value. Wherever there is a range I want to take the average
2. Depending on if the salary is hourly/weekly/yearly etc I want to add a column for salary type based on if there are substring characters such as ('year','month','week','hour' etc)

The final output should look like what is in the image below

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97xx7.png)

Thanks!

Comment: please have a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    splitted_value = df["salary"].iloc[i].split()
    salary_type = (splitted_value[-1]+"ly").title()
    if "-" in splitted_value:
        ranged_salary = [int(x.replace("$","").replace(",","")) for x in splitted_value if "$" in x]
        salary = sum(ranged_salary)/len(ranged_salary)
    else:
        salary = int(splitted_value[-3].replace("$","").replace(",",""))
    df.loc[i,"salary_value"] = salary
    df.loc[i,"salary_type"] = salary_type
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, but next time please provide the input data as something we can copy/paste.

What you need is a function that converts the string for the salary data into the value and the salary type.

You parse over the characters in the string to find the numbers, and use a boolean switch when you encounter the `-` (dash) character, in case you need to calculate an average.

```py
lst = [
    "Up to $80,000 a year",
    "$8,500 - $10,500 a month",
    "$25 - $40 an hour",
    "$1,546 a week"
]


def convert(salary_data: str):
    value = ""
    value_max = ""
    need_average = False
    # iterate over the characters in the string
    for c in salary_data:
        if c.isdigit():
            if need_average:
                value_max += c
            else:
                value += c
        elif c == "-":
            # switch to adding to value_max after finding the dash
            need_average = True
    if not need_average:
        # slight cheating for the f-string below
        value_max = value
    value = f"{(int(value) + int(value_max)) / 2:.2f}"
    if "hour" in salary_data:
        salary_type = "hourly"
    elif "week" in salary_data:
        salary_type = "weekly"
    elif "month" in salary_data:
        salary_type = "monthly"
    else:
        # use this as fallback
        salary_type = "yearly"
    return value, salary_type


for element in lst:
    value, salary_type = convert(element)
    print(value, salary_type)
```

**output**

```
80000.00 yearly
9500.00 monthly
32.50 hourly
1546.00 weekly
```